# ssh to docker container hosted on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ssh

I want to run a docker container on EC2 and also I need to ssh into the container for debugging purposes. I have 2 ports open for ssh 22 and 8022 on my EC2 instance(security group applied). The problem is when I want to bind 22 port of my docker container to port 8022 then it tells address already in use. And the address is used by sshd program. If I kill the process then I cant ssh to the instance from my localhost. How can I overcome this deadlock?

Comment: You usually don't ssh to containers.  ssh to the host, and `sudo docker exec` if you _really_ need an interactive shell.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the comments, you don't need to start ssh inside the container in order to go inside the container. You can use the docker exec command to go inside the container after you ssh into the EC2 instance by running:

```
docker exec -it <container-name> bash
```

If you still want to ssh into the container directly, then you need to do the following:

1. Start the container and map port 22 inside to a free port outside;

   `docker run -p 2222:22 ...`
2. After starting the container, exec into it and install ssh if not yet installed, and start the ssh service using something like `systemctl start sshd`
3. ssh into the container, by using the ec2 instance IP and the mapped port

   `ssh <container-user>@<ec2-instance-ip> -p 2222`

This will connect to the ec2 instance and redirect you into the container due to the port mapping.

Comment: Dear yamenk, I need to ssh into container for Pycharm remote debugging. I have done everything as described, but the problem is when I open a port in aws cloud to listen to ssh it is already in use by ssd of the instance, so I can't bind it anymore to docker container , because the port is already in use. You got my question wrong.

Comment: @user3338094 This is why you need to map the ssh port inside the container to a port different than 22 on the instance. You do that by adding `-p 2222:22` to the run command and configure the debugger to connect to port 2222 rather than 22.

Comment: And if 2222 port is not listening to sshd how would you ssh from localhost to remote server? One can only ssh to open ports and then that port should reconnect.

Comment: @user3338094 The `-p` option in docker is mapping the ports. The container is internally listening on port 22 if you start sshd inside. The port mapping will redirect traffic coming into port `2222` to `22` inside the container. This will allow you to open an ssh session directly into the container. In addition, you need to configure the security group of the ec2 instance to allow traffic on port 2222.